# Include Wordpress Core into own Scripts

Tags: wordpress, include

I'm trying to "Import" the Wordpress core into an own script to use the functionality such as wp_query etc. I've created an script in a subdirectory (own framework) and want to extend it by wordpress, but everytime the script throws an error:

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in **.../wordpress/wp-includes/taxonomy.php** on line **333**

such as (when I remove the add_action( 'init', 'create_initial_taxonomies', 0 )):

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in **.../wordpress/wp-includes/post.php** on line **1006**

The non-object is the $wp_rewrite-object. I've echo'ed something and figured out that first $wp_rewrite is valid and at the next call not. I've changed nothing at the WP core files.

I try to include the core by calling:

```
    require_once(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

Has anybody some ideas for me?

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer, do this:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

Long answer, it's a subtle gotcha around importing scripts with PHP.

If you define a local variable, outside of all functions, then it can be retrieved inside a function using 'global'. If you have a local variable inside a function, it cannot be retrieved later using global, unless it is defined as being global there and then.

The script 'wp-settings.php' is where the issue lies. It is included via your call to include 'wp-load.php'.

The variables defined there are *not* stated as being global; instead this is presumed because the script is always run outside of any functions, and so are automatically global. i.e.

```
$wordpress = 'foo';

function wordpressFunction() {
    global $wordpress;
}
```

Because you are importing the script within a function, they now become local variables. You are essentially doing:

```
function myFramework() {
    $wordpress = 'foo';

    function wordpressFunction() {
        global $wordpress;
    }
}
```

So the fix is to define them as global yourself before importing the script. Now $wp_query, and the others defined as global, are correctly found.

Comment: that I've also figured out after some testing. the scopes in wordpress drives someone sometimes crazy. when one is including the core within an function then the whole core has problems because the variables are in an unreadable scope

Comment: Adding the globals didn't seem to help me but it at least helped me identify the problem and I found loading wordpress in the global scope (instead of a function where it was being loaded) resolved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @EricAnderson I am guessing the globals may have changed.

Comment: @JL235 worked like a charm, and beautiful explanation

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to access everything wordpress has programmed in is to use the following:

```
require_once('/../../../wp-blog-header.php'); // Use actual root path to wp-blog-header.php
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
```

Using the above code you'll get all functions you would normally get using a template with in WordPress. I've tried all the other methods listed above and this one is by far the best.

Comment: Is the header required?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I wanted to get some articles along with permalinks. This helped:

```
global $wpdb, $wp_rewrite;
require '/(...)/wp-config.php';

$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( ... ) );
foreach( $result as &$item )
  $item->link = get_permalink( $item->ID );
```

I also found this useful in another case:
http://www.stormyfrog.com/using-wpdb-outside-wordpress/