# How to create a custom PHP hello world page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to createa menu item link that refers to a page where I can write something like:

```
<?php

echo 'hello world';

?>
```

this is what I mean by custom page, I see the examples but there people are creating templates, I just need a simple custom page is that possible?

Comment: Just dump your php file in the docroot and request it like you would normally do: `http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.php`

Comment: @PeeHaa yeah this is good, but not a wordpress way to do things :), so I can use in this custom file a wordpress core functions? if yes, thats really good, anyway I will use it, cause I don't have another choice :DD, also how could I create a menu link that will refer to this custom php file? it looks like little complicated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9101503/508666

Comment: @PeeHaa This is not the proper way to create a WordPress template - there is a standard naming convention that will automatically load the required functions.

Comment: @doublesharp As per OPs requirement from his question yeah "...but there people are creating templates, I just need a simple custom page..."

Comment: @PeeHaa I suppose you are technically correct, but there are lots of things to understand if you just use `wp-load.php` directly without passing it through `index.php`. Good sum up is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860577/wordpress-wp-load-php

Comment: And it really is as simple as adding `Template Name: Something` to the top of a PHP file in your theme, so I don't know why you would avoid that if you wanted was a page. It's also going to show up as a Page in WordPress that you can add to a menu rather than having to use a custom link.

Comment: And as one last comment - Otto (core WP developer) says "[Don't include wp-load, please.](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/)" and explains why it can be problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to create custom page templates in WordPress with the documentation found under [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). If you are developing your own theme, you can just use the naming conventions found under the [Template Files List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List), or if you are using a theme developed by someone else you should first create a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Child_Themes) and then add your custom templates under it. You can also make *any* PHP file under your theme a [Custom Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) by adding a comment at the top of the page. WordPress will automatically detect this file and the template will become accessible via the Page Edit screen in the WordPress Admin.

The short version - add a file called `page-custom-template.php` to your theme directory (typically `/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_DIR/` and add the following comment at the top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page Template
*/

// your code goes here
echo 'hello world';

?>
```

Comment: Great links for the beginner by the way. Simple to follow. I added a child theme in about 10 minutes.