# Functions in Wordpress's functions.php being redeclared when called from a standalone script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting a "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare function_name" error from all functions in functions.php when trying to write a standalone script.

A script with only the one line

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
```

triggers the error.

I could go through and add `function_exists()` conditionals to every one of the 100 or so functions, but that seems tedious on a site that works just fine otherwise.

Why would including wp-load.php from a standalone script try to redeclare these functions?  What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include Wordpress Core into own Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101503/include-wordpress-core-into-own-scripts)

Comment: @GrafiCode No, that causes the same problem.  I've included core into my own scripts on several sites before, that's not the problem.  But it's not working on this site for some reason and I have no explanation for it or what to check.

Comment: It sounds like the standalone script already loads the wp core... I mean, what if you list all defined functions with `get_defined_functions` without including the wp-load file, does it list all functions in functions.php?

Comment: @GrafiCode Nope, nothing from functions.php is in the list.

Comment: You should always wrap your functions with `function_exists()`. If you manually include **wp-load.php** this file will be include (once) **wp-config.php** and **wp-settings.php** and inside **wp-setings.php** file, there are a lot of `include`/`require` (not once) on many files. These may cause of redeclare error because they were include/require many times.

Comment: @vee My question is why doesn't it cause problems on the main site, which obviously calls wp-load and all those others?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that question about _problems on the main site_ anywhere.

Comment: @vee I guess more specifically, I'm trying to figure out what's going on... the main site works fine.  But when I make a standalone script that only includes the library to load the main site, that doesn't work.  The same line works just fine on other wordpress sites (whose functions.php also does not have the function_exists() wrapper).

Comment: Which functions.php are we talking about - that from `/wp-includes/`, or one from a custom theme?

Comment: Assuming you have a wp-settings.php, that one will be required, and then in turn requires the functions.php, but without any `_once`, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L111=, and later on a functions.php from the theme folder will also just be `include`-ed. Not sure at what point that could cause a doubled embedding of the file(s) though, when your script does a include_once to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe It's the standard functions.php that goes in every theme.